# Bootstrap grid: How to change the place of a column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I have a question regarding a bootstrap grid system I am trying to achieve - and have not been successful so far.

I am trying to do the following grid system:

[image]

I have tried a code that you'll find with [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awenig/crzjd15k).

```
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 border bg-primary" style="height: 200px">
          <h3>Bloc 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 border bg-light">
          <h3>Bloc 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 bg-danger">
          <h3>Bloc 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It works well for **xs** and **md** system. However, I have issues with the **lg** version, where I don't find a way to stack the bloc number 2 (grey) on top of the bloc number 3 (red). Is there a way to change the place of such a column? As indicated on the figure above, the bloc number 1 should fall to the bottom of the page.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't see where you've implemented [column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#reordering).

Comment: Thank you @isherwood for your reply. Yes I have not so far ; because I don't see how ordering can help me. The main issue is that on **lg** the blue column needs to fall to the bottom of the page ; while on **md** it needs to stop at the same level as the grey column. And I don't succeed if finding a way to achieve this with Bootstrap ; if you have any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't notice at first that you have a nested row. That would break ordering using Bootstrap classes. Is there a reason you need nested rows?

Comment: There is no reason, actually. Sorry for this mistake. I have updated the code here, as well as in the JSFiddle. There are three columns. The main issue remains with the **lg** system, where I cannot offset six columns for instance because I want the blue bloc (no. 1) to fall tot he bottom of the page (the reason is that this bloc is sticky-top) on **lg** devices.

Comment: I would suggest you switch to a mobile-first way of thinking also. Your classes are listed in reverse order of what Bootstrap and most devs would do it, and your images are reversed as well.  In the Bootstrap CSS larger breakpoints override smaller ones, so they come later.

Comment: I've spent some time with this problem and I'm not sure it can be done with Bootstrap classes. You many need to work it up as a custom flexbox situation.

Comment: Thank you @isherwood for your first advice. Regarding your second comment, thanks. I'll stop trying to find a Bootstrap solution then and will try with a custom solution. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I would suggest you try with native CSS Grid, changing the layout is as simple as changing one css property (grid-template-areas) for a given media query.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to wrap a div for a second column around the gray and red divs

```
<div class="container ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 border bg-primary" style="height: 200px">
          <h3>Bloc 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12"><!--NEW DIV, moved column info here-->
          <div class=" border bg-light">
            <h3>Bloc 2</h3>
          </div>
          <div class=" bg-danger">
            <h3>Bloc 3</h3>
          </div>
        </div><!--new div end-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

You will need to work out the tweaks for spacing, but this is a start

[image]